# How do I linkify text in Perl?

Tags: perl, url, hyperlink

I have some text I want to linkify, which I can reasonably do with a regex (search for http/https or www) but I'm worried about XSS complications.  What's a safe way to do this in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly what do you mean by XSS complications? Are you only concerned with JavaScript or do URLs of the form http://example.com/command?type=delete;who=sam etc concern you as well?

As for linkifying URLs, there will always be edge cases, but [Text::Markdown](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Markdown)  worked pretty well on a variety of inputs when I tried it. You can use the [urls](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Markdown#urls) method to preprocess the links.

See also [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/).

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the XSS issue, but [URI::Find](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI-Find) will let you find all URIs in text and transform them into whatever you like.