# Perl regex to match URIs in a string

Tags: regex, perl, url

I'm having a bit of a problem with a regex in Perl.

Assume I'm getting a string with URIs embedded somewhere in it. I'd like to store every unique URI.

My problem is that URIs in that string might have different formats. Some might be `mylightsaber24.com`, others might be `http://www.companyabc.co.uk` or even `www.thisisawebsite.com/index.html?someparameters`.

For that reason, both `Regexp::Common qw /URI/` and `Regexp::Common qw/net/` failed me :(

Any pointers?

Thanks so much!

Bonus points for identifying that `www.nomansland.com`and `nomansland.com` are basically the same entry.

Comment: Just FYI, *www.nomanskland.com* and *nomansland.com* could be diferent entries.

Comment: What do you want to do for the case where the string is just a host name? It would be a lot of work to check for anything ending in the [Public Suffix List](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1) but flagging anything with a dot in it would claim that `St.Augustine`, `B.B.C.` and `3.14` were all URLs.

Comment: Found and installed http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/URI-Find-20111103/lib/URI/Find/Schemeless.pm which seems suitable enough. I'll have a look at what problems I'll run into with edge cases.

Comment: related [How do I linkify text in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608094/how-do-i-linkify-text-in-perl)

Comment: @msallge: You will need the `URI::Find::Schemeless` variant (part of the same module) otherwise most of your URLs will be ignored.

Comment: Borodin, not a lot of work: [Mozilla::PublicSuffix](http://p3rl.org/Mozilla::PublicSuffix)

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks. That's what I did. Works good (enough). :)

Answer (score 2):

What's about these CPAN modules:

- [Regexp::Common::URI::http](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2011121001/lib/Regexp/Common/URI/http.pm)
- [URI](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.60/URI.pm)

Comment: `Regexp::Common::URI::http` will match only a full absolute URI and not a bare host name. `URI` is useful for verifying that a complete string represents a valid URL but will not find all URLs within a string.